# Move file from one Google Compute Engine VM to another in the same zone?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 Google Compute Engine VMs in the same zone. How can I move a file from one VM to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`gcloud compute copy-files`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) to copy data between your GCE instances or your local machine.

Comment: Actually `gcloud compute copy-files ` is deprecated. You should use `gcloud compute scp`. Be sure to set proper `Cloud API access scopes` in both `VMs` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58285300/2047442).

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to move file from vm_1 to storage bucket and from storage to vm_2.

to do so in vm_1 run command `gsutil cp your_file gs://your_bucket` and from bucket to vm_2 in the vm_2 run command `gsutil cp gs://your_bucket/your_file .` This way you will have the same file backed up in a storage bucket.

Comment: If you're having trouble making this work, be sure your VM instance has READ and WRITE access to storage API and use sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Faizan's answer and @irudyak's comment, an example of a full gcloud compute scp command copying a folder between VMs across different projects, and after setting up the appropriate permissions (i.e. logging in w an gcloud account with appropriate access to both projects via `gcloud auth login` or otherwise), would be:

`gcloud compute scp --recurse example-folder --project project-b prj-b-dev-vm:/home/user/ --zone europe-west1-b --ssh-key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

The `--ssh-key-file` option is optional, and is useful if the receiving VM already has the ssh key as a known_host and in the `.ssh` folder (otherwise `gcloud compute scp` will automatically create a new ssh-key in order to access the receiving VM)