# How to copy all folders from one Google Cloud instances to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I made new instance by rebooting the disk of older one but inside folder, no data has transferred.
Trying to make new instance(server) after copying the older one to new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy files between two Google Cloud instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235349/copy-files-between-two-google-cloud-instances)

Comment: gcloud compute scp [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC …] [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST [--compress] [--dry-run] [--force-key-file-overwrite] [--plain] [--port=PORT] [--recurse] [--scp-flag=SCP_FLAG] [--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE] [--strict-host-key-checking=STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING] [--zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]   anyone can explain? do we need to create ssh on source instance?

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: This question is more suited to Serverfault where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators).